# R workspace wiped

Tags: r, rstudio, recovery

I have spent the last few months on an important research project. I checked in on it again today after not touching it for about 2 weeks. The workspace is how it was around 3 months ago, and it does not have any of my most important data frames, tables, etc. The history, if I search for a command I used to assign the data (e.g. df="blah"), it is still there. How can I recover my workspace? It didn't have any error messages. My computer died a few times, but I don't know if that would impact it as I had it saved more recently than 3 months ago.

If I can't recover the workspace, how can I view the full history? I have tried saving the history as a .txt file, but it only shows the history from 3 months ago. The window also only shows this shortened history. However, again, if I actually search the window, it shows commands more recent than that. I don't know how to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the history pane, select the lines you want to keep and click on "To Source". This will open a script file, that you then save as a .R file. But this gets to what your workflow should really be - everything you run in R should be saved in script files in order to be able to reproduce your analysis at a later date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.